# remover checked de input radio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como consigo remover checked de input radio caso uma div tenha o efeito click?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>
 <div id="remover">
  <p>Remover checked de radio selecinado</p>
 </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Quando a div com id "remover" tiver efeito de click remover checked de input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto irá resolver seu problema:

```
<div id="remover" onclick="$('input[name=gender]').prop('checked', false);">
```

Ou:

```
$( "#remover" ).click(function() {
    $('input[name=gender]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

---

EDIT - 
Possibilidade de resolver o problema com javascript puro:

```
<div id="remover" onclick="removerChecked();">

<script>
    function removerChecked() {
        var ele = document.getElementsByName("gender");
        for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
           ele[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Isso se ele tiver jQuery correto?

Comment: Correto, e dentre as tags da pergunta jQuery está marcado.

Comment: Só comentei pq no código que ele postou não tem o include do jQuary, mas se está na tag da pergunta está tranquilo.

Comment: Sem problemas, editei a resposta para possibilitar quem não queira jQuery também ser ajudado futuramente.

Comment: Muito bom, tmj!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode resetar o `form` (desmarcando tudo) usando `.reset()` com um simples código (caso o `form` tenha apenas *radio buttons*):

```js
$("#remover").click(function(){
   $("form")[0].reset();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>
<div id="remover">
   <p>Remover checked de radio selecinado</p>
</div>
```

#### Ou com JavaScript puro:

```js
document.querySelector("#remover").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
   document.querySelector("form").reset();
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>
<div id="remover">
   <p>Remover checked de radio selecinado</p>
</div>
```

Comment: A desvantagem dessa sugestão é que se ele adicionar novos campos no formulário dele, essa ação irá limpar o formulário por completo. E isso pode ser inconveniente.

Comment: @DavidAlves É verdade. Mas a resposta está baseada apenas no escopo da pergunta.

Comment: @DavidAlves Mas a sua resposta está bem elaborada, Vou até dar +1.

Comment: Entendo. A sua está muito boa também. Só fiz um comentário para quem estiver procurando essa solução futuramente saber a diferença. Mas a sua resposta é muito útil se o intuito for limpar o formulário inteiro.